# How to detect Facebook like button being clicked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-like

I've implemented a Facebook like button using this code:

```
FBLikeControl *like = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];
like.objectID = @"1031992973496678";
[like setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 100)];
[[self view] addSubview:like];
```

I would like to have the button disappear when it is pressed, using this code:

```
[like removeFromSuperview];
```

How would I detect when the like button is pressed?

Edit: I am currently using this code to detect when the like button is being pressed, but the NSLogs and like button's presence indicate the selector is not being used:

```
[like addTarget:self action:@selector(likePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[[self view] addSubview:like];



- (void) likePressed:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"GG, like was pressed!");
[sender removeFromSuperview];
[likeText removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I have tried substituting `[sender removeFromSuperview];` with `[like removeFromSuperview];`, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing UIControlEventValueChanged to UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Answer (score 3):

Check out the docs for `FBLikeControl` here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBLikeControl

It looks like the `FBLikeControl` inherits from `UIControl` and sends information through the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event. Try add a listener for this event then remove the view:

```
[likeControl addTarget:self action:@selector(likePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// ... then later

-(void)likePressed:(id)sender {

    [sender removeFromSuperview];    

}
```

Comment: I have done this, but the code within likePressed is not being run, according to NSLogs and the like button not disappearing.

Comment: I added an edit to my original post with code I am currently using to try to detect the like button being pressed.

Comment: Another person filled in the missing piece. Thanks! :)

Comment: Funny that Facebook's documentation is wrong. glad you figured it out :)